What should I do about paper, felt, and wood layers under wallpaper?
Wondering if anyone has encountered this in older homes... After taking down some wallpaper we found a thick layer of brown paper over what looks like felt, directly over some kind of wood slats. No one locally seems to know what it is and have mostly recommended putting up 1/4 drywall over the existing wallpaper. We found this post (What is this wall covering in our 1908 USA house?)  where someone has the same material, but no clear answer.
The concern: Seems like it's not paintable, or would be a real pita. There are different patches of wallpaper over the wood, probably to create a smooth surface when top layer of vinyl was applied. I've read that putting drywall over wallpaper can sometimes cause issues with moisture/mold, which we obviously don't want! We're also considering putting up more wallpaper, but... we don't want to have to do that every time we decide to change the look of the walls  Would love to paint.
Any advice would be great! This is my first home (built in 1916, USA) and every. single. room. is covered in wallpaper, and we're assuming the same stuff is underneath. Thanks for any insight!




I don't know an English word. Here in Germany it is called "Renovierflies" and it used to be common in older homes to prepare walls that were otherwise considered unsuitable to be papered over directly - just a thin layer to hide imperfections from the wall. Probably not very useful because it has pretty much fallen out of favour.

"I've read that putting drywall over wallpaper can sometimes cause issues with moisture/mold" got any credible sources for that? Sounds like an old wive's tale to me.

@FreeMan not exactly... just reddit, different websites, other forums, etc. When we've asked contractors or painters they seem to think is possible but don't flag it as a major concern. I think that's part of why we're confused - many internet opinions point to it as an issue, real life people are "meh" about it.

Lots of things are possible. I mean, your roof could collapse tonight. How likely is it and what kind of issues will it cause. Heck, even a painted wall can develop mold... Unfortunately, opinions on the internet are like... well, you get the idea...

Ha good point, fair enough ... and true, the internet can be a magical and scary place

You can apply plasterboard over existing plaster, rather than stripping the wall down first. You may need extensions on the electrical boxes, and it will confuse anyone cutting/drilling into that wall just as the current layers confuse you, but it isn't an uncommon solution. I have an instance of this in my own house, sheetrock over plaster-and-lath.

Thank you! Two follow-ups: (1) It sounds like you didn't take out the plaster & lath down to the studs first? (since it's otherwise sturdy we didn't want to open that can of worms) (2) What sort of prep did you do before the sheetrock? I'm in a wet climate and a bit hyper worried about mold

What is your worry about mold? Older houses like this tend to 'breathe' as they don't have any strong vapor barriers. If you're worried about bulk water getting in from the outside, nothing you do on the inside is going to fix that problem. If you're worried about vapor migration from the inside, properly sized air conditioning will probably help you there since it removes latent heat as well.

@KMJ Paranoia, I suppose? I did read that sometimes blowing new insulation old homes (which one guy we spoke to suggested) can cause an issue as it stops the home from "breathing", and can trap moisture
– was curious if drywall could cause a similar issue. We haven't been able to find any info on this particular type of wall material either and wasn't sure if it would react differently than plaster, beaverboard, old drywall, etc. This is all coming from a place of knowing nothing and trying to interpret what we're finding out...

Good luck with it. The entire subject of vapor moisture in a house is a rabbit hole you can absolutely dive deep into. For an old house like this, your biggest worry should be bulk water from outside most of the time.

How old is the house, and when was it last completely resided? In my place there's nothing vaguely resembling a moisture barrier, and even after air-sealing the foundation and super insulating the attic (easy, highest bang for the buck) and then doing blown-in it isn't as airtight as a modern high-efficiency build. I wouldn't worry about mold unless something is actually becoming soggy.

@keshlam it was built in 1916 and the sellers left a record of a having siding installed in 1973 (they left the old product booklet for "Alsco Premium 30 with tedlar", which is pretty cool). Says it has a "40 year guarantee", but the inspector didn't flag any issues with the siding from the exterior. Thanks for sharing your experience as well, I'm just hoping we don't make any wrong turns with the updates we make!

@keshlam Any thoughts on beadboard instead of drywall? It isn't something I see come up as often and I'm wondering if there are any downsides?

Requests for opinions are out of scope here. Not that I have any in this case; as far as I can tell it's a matter of preference and budget. Your local fire codes may have something to say about how thick the headboard would have to be to be used alone. Closest I've gotten to that was considering whether I wanted to do the workshop in plywood.
